# Dicas para se transformar código procedural em orientado a objeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um sistema que está totalmente no estilo procedural, e quero saber quais são os pontos de que preciso identificar para transformar esse código em orientado a objeto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tive tal procedimento em um site que eu mesmo desenvolvi quando `PHP` não tinha `POO` ainda. O grande problema é entender a regra de negócio atual e traduzir a Programação Orientada a Objeto. São coisas diferentes, e a principal meta sua é entender o Procedural e Analisar antes de implementar em POO.

Dica:

1) O que o seu sistema faz ?

Exemplo: Faz um cadastro de cliente, como você pode reaproveitar alguma coisa, talvez a View e alguns código, mas, em termos reais, a parte codigo terá que ser reescrita, é um trabalho grande.

2) Posso reaproveitar código ?

Exemplo: As `SQL` você pode aproveitar, acredito que são iguais ou praticamente. Agora com certeza vai ter que usar `PDO` ou `MySqli`, então, ai começa as alterações.

3) Vale a pena mudar ou fazer outro?

Muitas vezes é melhor projetar em POO um novo sistema que possa ser feito em paralelo ao antigo, evitando assim a parada do sistema, e dando enfase ao novo sistema.

4) Trabalhar com Padrões ?

Eu indico trabalhar com padrões e nomenclaturas atuais, *interfaces*, *abstract*, *class*. Um fator importante é saber POO bem, e talvez até implementar com *Frameworks MVC*, exemplo, [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) ou [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) (indico Laravel é mais rápido o aprendizado, o Zend a curva de aprendizado é maior)

5) Código Procedural para Código POO, cuidado?

Cuidado, como já foi relatado POO é conceito, siga os conceitos POO e faça um novo código com tais conceito. Experiência: uma vez trabalhei numa equipe que tinha a programação em Cobol e eles começaram a fazer um sistema em VB6, o que aconteceu, tudo que eles faziam no Cobol eles replicavam no VB6, isso foi o pior absurdo que eu já presenciei.

Comment: Boa resposta, muitos pontos relevantes. Destaco: *"é melhor projetar em POO um novo sistema que possa ser feito em paralelo ao antigo"*.

Answer (score 5):

Participei de um projeto recentemente onde tive que portar um sistema desktop programado em VB6 para ASP.NET C# OO (3 camadas).

Minha análise foi a seguinte:

- Entender como o sistema(e cada página dele) funciona e como usá-lo (Identificar o que é o que e pra que serve).
- Entender a regra de negócio (isso é muito importante pois você pode encontrar restrições que acabam quebrando outras páginas que dependem dessa regra).
- Identificar os objetos e métodos do sistema e listá-los.
- Procurar por funções e métodos que podem se tornar genéricos.

*Como OO é um conceito creio que minha experiência pode te ajudar*